# Prevent VMWare from saving to (host) disk

Tags: memory, vmware

I want to run an Ubuntu live disk inside VMWare. However, I do not want the OS to write to the virtual disk. I instead just want it all to be stored in memory, and shutdown completely when I am done. Is this at all possible?

Comment: If everything else fails, create a snapshot before booting with the live cd and then revert to the snapshot afterwards.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. You can boot from a live disk inside the virtual machine without it writing to the virtual disk at all. It's no different than booting from a live usb on your physical host in that regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the virtual disk at all, then you can simply remove it from the VM settings.  Then that guarantees that the live CD won't write anything.

If you need the live CD to be able to *read* from a virtual disk, you probably could make the `.vmdk` files read-only.  Alternatively, you could take a snapshot of the VM beforehand and configure the VM to automatically revert to the snapshot when powering off.

Comment: Removing the drive worked. I wish I could also disable snapshots, but that option doesn't seem available in the free VMWare Player.